# can color-theme bind to a buffer?

Tags: emacs

I want to use different color-theme for different file types. I tried to use **add-hook** to set the color-theme for the major-mode, but it only applies when the buffer is first load. If I switch to another buffer and switch back, the color-theme will stay the same as it is in the previous buffer. Then I tried to set the **window-configuration-change-hook**, but the window blinks every time I press C-x, or M-x, or whatever that change the window properties.

Is there a better way to set the color-theme for each buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you happen to be using emacs 24, `color-theme-buffer-local` in the package manager will do what you want.

[The version here](https://github.com/vic/color-theme-buffer-local/blob/master/color-theme-buffer-local.el) reportedly works with 23.